# How to get response.context information on the client side in an Angular application?

Tags: javascript, python, angular, typescript, fetch-api

So I am trying to create an Angular application and the server end point sends the following information (it's created in Python).

```
 gltf = create_gltf(vertices, trig_faces, uv)
        data = b"".join(gltf.save_to_bytes())
        data_size = {"size": len(data)}
        log.info(f"Length of the content is  {len(data)}")
        response.content_type = MEDIA_GLTF
        response.context = data_size
        response.data = b"".join(gltf.save_to_bytes())
        response.status = falcon.HTTP_200
```

On the client side, I have used fetch api to receive the server response. It is stated below as the following:

```
const data$ = new Observable(observer => {
            fetch(targetUrl.toString(), { headers: { 'responseType': 'application/octet-stream' }, method: 'GET' })
                .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
                .then(gltf => {
                    observer.next(gltf);
                    observer.complete();
                })
                .catch(err => observer.error(err));
        });
        let result = data$.pipe(
            map(gltfAsArrayBuffer => {
                let gltfObject: any = {
                    'componentId': componentId,
                    'gltfBytes': gltfAsArrayBuffer,
                };
                    this.surfaceMeshesGltf.set(surfaceMeshKey, gltfObject);
            })
        );
        return result;
```

I was wondering how do I access the context information that I am sending over from the backend on the client side (the context information in this case is the size of the data being sent).

Comment: You probably don't. Look at the HTTP response you get from the server. You can see everything it contains in the browser's network inspector. What's not in there cannot be gotten. You need to return the data either in some header, or the response body.

Comment: And how would I be able to do that?

Comment: Do what exactly? Can you include the additional data in the response body somehow? Can you include it in the header? What makes sense?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for being unclear, I was wondering how do I include it in the header? Because when I tried doing that, I receive an error. response.headers = data_size
AttributeError: can't set attribute

Comment: Rather something like `response.headers['X-Size'] = len(data)`…?

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot. In the frontend, I receive the data this way, right? response.headers.get("Size"). It's giving null for some reason.

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot. I figured it out at the end. Thanks for your help! :)